# how to find the number of different arrangements when a coin is thrown 12 times and gets 5 heads

Tags: permutations

Suppose a fair coin which has 2 faces-Head(H) and Tail(T) is thrown 12 times and 
we get exactly 5 heads:
  $$H,H,H,H,H,T,T,T,T,T,T,T$$
How can I find the number of different arrangements it can have?
One possible arrangement:

$$H,T,T,H,T,T,H,H,T,T,T,H$$
Another possible arrangement:
$$ H,H,H,T,T,T,T,T,T,T,H,H$$

I can find the probability of getting exactly 5 heads by using binomial distribution but i cannot find the actual number of arrangements.

Comment: Please negative voter,tell the reason.

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but I agree that this question has issues. One, You start to talk about a dice, and the title is about a coin. Two, you did not show your work so far: what did you try, how far did you get, where are you stuck?

Comment: Another problem is that this just looks like a homework question. (I am not the negative voter by the way. I have seen a lot posts which are worse)

Comment: i hope this is fine now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the binomial coefficient $\binom{12}{5}$, i.e., $\dfrac{12!}{5!(12-5)!}$.  This corresponds to the number of different ways of placing the $5$ heads in the $12$ positions.